# Your attitude and work ethic “reflect...” or “reflects...”?

Tags: grammar

Which of the following sentences would be correct?

1. "Your attitude and work ethic **reflect** your desire to succeed."
2. "Your attitude and work ethic **reflects** your desire to succeed."

Comment: Google Books has 7 instances of [*his attitude and work ethic **are**,*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22his+attitude+and+work+ethic+are%22) and 8 of [*his attitude and work ethic **is***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22his+attitude+and+work+ethic+is%22). That's not *exactly* "six of one and half-a-dozen of the other", but I'd say it's as near as makes no difference. In short, the "plurality" of the subject is effectively a stylistic choice in your cited context.

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of opinion. If the implied meaning is: [*Your attitude*] and [*your work ethic*] -- then it should be **reflect**, to make the verb agree with the [compound subject](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/diagrams2/one_pager1.htm).

But since the compound nature of the subject is not overtly expressed, the subject is more likely to be interpreted as being singular (although [complex](http://A%20complex%20subject%20is%20one%20that%20uses%20modifiers%20to%20add%20information%20to%20the%20simple%20subject.)): Your [*attitude and work ethic*] -- so it may sound more natural to most people using the third person singular form of the verb: **reflects**.

In the first case, [your attitude] and [your work ethic] are treated as two separate issues, whereas in the latter, your [attitude and work ethic] are treated as one *collective* issue, conjoined by **and** as a coordinator meaning [*in addition to*](http://www.talkenglish.com/grammar/conjunctions-coordinating-correlative.aspx).